# A question about measurable sets with positive measure?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $E,F$ be measurable sets with positive measure. Does there exist a translate of $F$ such that it intersects $E$ with positive measure? I feel like this should be true, but can’t think of a proof.

Comment: Are $E,F$ subsets of $\mathbb R$? Or $\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: @MikeEarnest- $R$

Comment: Can you prove it instead for intervals? Then, can you use this fact to prove it for the general case? Hint: Regularity

Answer (score 1):

Fubini's Theorem yields a simple proof: if the conclusion is false then  $\int \mu (E \cap (F+x)) dx=0$ Write$\mu (E \cap (F+x)) =\int I_E (y) I_{F+x} (y) \, d\mu (y)$  and interchange the two integrals. You get $\int \int I_{F+x} (y) \, dx I_E (y) \, dy$. Note that $I_{F+x} (y) \equiv I_{y-F} (x)$ . Also Lebesgue measure of $y-F$ is same as Lebesgue measure of $F$.  Finally we get $\mu (E) \mu (F)=0$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: In my answer I have assume joint measurability of $I_{F+x}I_E(y)$. This function is composition of the two measurable functions $(x,y) \to (y,y-x)$ and $I_{E \times F}$